# Concatenate two columns into one column in a view in MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.6

I am trying to create a view and would like to display the firstName and lastName columns from a table as one column (User) in a view.

The view is using a left join. What I would like to do is join on userID from tableA with concat of firstName and lastName from tableB.

Is this possible in MySql? I have seen some proposed solutions for SQL Server.

Instead of displaying emailAddress column as per below view, I want to display a concat of firstName and lastName columns.

```
create or replace view document.Documents
as
select
    d.documentID
    ,cu.emailAddress as createdByUser
from document.Document as d
        left join customer.User as cu
            on cu.userID = d.recCreatedByUserID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [concat_ws](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS  
  SELECT concat_ws(' ', firstName, lastName) as "User" 
  FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the initial answer. I updated the question to reflect a more detailed scenario of what I am trying to achieve.